# How much time passes between each of the Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars

Am trying to find a definitive official timeline of the star wars universe. Taking phantom menace as a starting point I want to know how much in universe time passes between each movie.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history

Comment: Downvoting due to *lack of research*  A simple google search got me the answer

Comment: also a bit broad as asked. Including legends, or just the on-screen canon? If Disney canon that gets dicey because nearly everything is canon since the merger. Comics, books, tv, etc...

Comment: @VogonPoet by your logic, this site will have millions and millions of questions. I’m sorry to tell you but StackExchange sites (all of them) are for the questions that you couldn’t find answers for or it’s difficult to find the explanations behind something.

Comment: Upvoted for usefulness. It seems we’ve missed this on SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time in the Star Wars galaxy is measured in years around the Battle of Yavin in which the Death Star weapon was destroyed.  Years before that battle are suffixed with BBY, and dates after that battle are suffixed with ABY.

Based on [dates presented in Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history), The films occur in the following order:

- **32BBY** *Episode I – The Phantom Menace*
- **22BBY** *Episode II – Attack of the Clones*
- **19BBY** *Episode III – Revenge of the Sith*
- **13BBY** *Solo: A Star Wars Story*
- **0BBY** *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*
- **0BBY** *Episode IV – A New Hope*
- **3ABY** *Episode V – The Empire Strikes Back*
- **4ABY** *Episode VI – Return of the Jedi*
- **34ABY** *Episode VII – The Force Awakens*
- **34ABY** *Episode VIII – The Last Jedi*
- **35ABY** *Episode IX – The Rise of Skywalker*

For years as measured on the planet Lothal, use the [Lothal calendar system](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lothal_Calendar) by simply adding 3233 years to the ABY date.

Comment: A friendly suggestion: You might want to move Episode VI further down the list to make it clear it happened after Episode V. As it now stands, you seem to be listing it between IV and V. (I thought of just going in and editing it myself, but that seemed needlessly pushy.)

Comment: Okay, I shifted that line down a notch. As I said, I was reluctant to tamper with your text without warning.